# How to use Tokens in Views Filter - Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, view, token

I'm trying to filter a view based on the title of the node it is in. Pretty much I want to make the filter Content: Title(=[node:title]) but that is not working. Is there any work around for this or am I not doing something right?

Answer (score 0):

Make a contextual filter for content:title, then tell it to provide a default value, using the node id from the current page. [image: Example]